# Join lines perfect to each other in AI

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo

[image: Visual description of the problem]

The other red line is set to opacity 50% and is closed. I'd like to join them to later subtract them from from the basic picture (the fill) or make it white, but how to join them perfectly?

Comment: I am a bit curious though, why would it matter if the computer allowed you to do this versus you layering them on top so you cant see the difference? Why would you want the program to be this much more complicated, when most people have hard enough problems with the simplest of concepts.

Comment: I'd like to make sections with different colors. But it'll do with gradient transitions  hidden in the lines, but I was aiming for paint bucket.

Comment: paint bucket conceptually just builds new shapes you can put gap detection on so then you dont need to be so accurate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the background is jpeg or Image 
Re-create the curves using pen tool. Not necessarily same color for the mean time. Re color it later. 
[image]

Select the paths the red target and the curve edges
[image]

Use the Shape builder tool (Shift+M); then Press Alt + click the unwanted areas
[image]

You can re color it to see the changes
[image]

Option 2 - Given the paths are layered; just put the red path behind. it will hide the corners 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You **can't** connect paths in the middle of segments with Illustrator. It's simply **not** possible.

Paths can only be connected at anchor points. And even then, you are only permitted *2 path segments per anchor point*. Never any more than two.

Comment: So only solution to make this look better is to arrange the transparent part in front and hide these line(s). Thanks for the answer.